# Webpage using @media CSS rule to prevent printing

Tags: css, firefox, printing-web-page

I have a website which I want to print to PDF using Firefox.

I can see the website correctly on the screen, but printing it results in an empty white page.

By using the Firefox Inspector Tool, I have discovered that the problem resides in the webpage using CSS rules to declare elements hidden when printing, through the [`@media` css at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).

It does something like:

```
@media print {
    div.no-print,
    div.no-print * {
        display: hidden !important;
    } 
}
```

How can I print my page like it is showed on the screen?

Comment: Ok, rewrote with debugging info

Comment: Are you saying every div is in the no-print class?

Comment: No, just some of them

Comment: "Media query is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3." [source](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: @Rob [Here are the media query history in CSS standard](https://www.w3.org/standards/history/mediaqueries-3/)

Comment: While this is a legitimate question, and I personally didn't downvote it, it lacks any substance for us to go on. We can't just guess which elements are set not to print, and there may be other factors (a common one being that the printing system has been set not to print background images for example).  So please put up a runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem to give us something to work with.

Comment: Since it set "div.no-print" and "div.no-print *", I think every div element with "no-print" class, as well as all its children, are set not to print. I wouldn't know how to make a snippet since that is a real website

Comment: @A Haworth since my answer below fixes the problem, the problem is not that the printing system is set not to print background images

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to overwrite this CSS with our own:

1. Download [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) Firefox add-on
2. Overwrite the CSS:

```
@media print{
    div.no-print,
    div.no-print * {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
}
```

Remember to re-define the display attribute for elements for which it should not be that, for example tables:

```
@media print{

    div.no-print table {
        display: table !important;
    }
        
    div.no-print table thead
    {
        display: table-header-group !important;
    }
    
    div.no-print table tfoot
    {
        display: table-footer-group !important;
    }
    
    div.no-print table tbody
    {
        display: table-row-group !important;
    }
    
    div.no-print table td {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
    
    div.no-print table col {
        display: table-column !important;
    }
    
    div.no-print table tr {
        display: table-row !important;
    }
}
```